# Using metaclasses in order to define methods, class methods / instance methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, metaclass, class-method

I am trying to understand deeper how metaclasses work in python. My problem is the following, **I want to use metaclasses in order to define a method for each class which would use a class attribute defined within the metaclass.** For instance, this has application for registration.

Here is a working example:

```
import functools


def dec_register(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_register(*args, **kwargs):
        (args[0].__class__.list_register_instances).append(args[0])
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper_register




dict_register_classes = {}
class register(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, attrs):
        dict_register_classes[name] = cls = type.__new__(meta, name, bases, attrs)  # assigniation from right to left
        cls.list_register_instances = []
        cls.print_register = meta.print_register
        return cls

    def print_register(self):
        for element in self.list_register_instances:
            print(element)

    def print_register_class(cls):
        for element in cls.list_register_instances:
            print(element)

#
class Foo(metaclass=register):
    @dec_register
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def print_register(self):
        pass

class Boo(metaclass=register):
    @dec_register
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def print_register(self):
        pass

f = Foo()
f_ = Foo()
b = Boo()
print(f.list_register_instances)
print(b.list_register_instances)
print(dict_register_classes)

print("1")
f.print_register()
print("2")
Foo.print_register_class()
print("3")
f.print_register_class()
print("4")
Foo.print_register()
```

The test I am making at the end do not work as I was expected. I apologize in advance if what I am saying is not using the proper syntax, I am trying to be as clear as possible :

I was thinking that the line `cls.print_register = meta.print_register` is defining a method within the class using the method defined within the metaclass. Thus it is a method that I can use on an object. I can also use it a class method since it is defined in the metaclass. However, though the following works :

```
print("1")
f.print_register()
```

this do not work correctly :

```
print("4")
Foo.print_register()
```

with error :

```
Foo.print_register()
TypeError: print_register() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Same for test 2 and 3, where I was expecting that if a method is defined on the class level, it should also be defined on the object level. However, test 3 is raising an error.

```
print("2")
Foo.print_register_class()
print("3")
f.print_register_class()
```

**Hence, can you please explain me how come my understanding of class methods is wrong ? I would like to be able to call the method `print_register` either on the class or on the object.**

---

Perhaps it could help to know that in fact I was trying to reproduce the following very simple example :

```
# example without anything fancy:
class Foo:
    list_register_instances = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__.list_register_instances.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def print_register(cls):
        for element in cls.list_register_instances:
            print(element)
```

Am I not doing the exact same thing with a metaclass ? A classmethod can be used either on a class or on objects.

Also if you have any tips about code structure I would greatly appreciate it. I must be very bad at the syntax of metaclasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, because you have *shadowed* `print_register` on your instance of the metaclass (your class).

So when you do `Foo.print_register`, it finds the `print_register` you defined in

```
class Foo(metaclass=register):
    ...
def print_register(self):
    pass
```

Which of course, is just the plain function `print_register`, which requires the `self` argument.

This is (almost) the same thing that would happen with just a regular class and it's instances:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print("I am a bar")

foo = Foo()

foo.bar = lambda x: print("I've hijacked bar")

foo.bar()
```

Note:

```
In [1]: class Meta(type):
   ...:     def print_register(self):
   ...:         print('hi')
   ...:

In [2]: class Foo(metaclass=Meta):
   ...:     pass
   ...:

In [3]: Foo.print_register()
hi

In [4]: class Foo(metaclass=Meta):
   ...:     def print_register(self):
   ...:         print('hello')
   ...:

In [5]: Foo.print_register()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a42427fde947> in <module>
----> 1 Foo.print_register()

TypeError: print_register() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

However, you do this *in your metaclass constructor as well!*

```
cls.print_register = meta.print_register
```

Which is effectively like defining that function in your class definition... not sure why you are doing this though.

You are *not* doing the exact same thing as using a `classmethod`, which is a custom descriptor that handles the binding of methods to instances in just the way you'd need to be able to call it on a class or on an instance. That is *not* the same as defining a method on the class and on the instance! You could just do this in your metaclass `__new__`, i.e. `cls.print_register = classmethod(meta.print_register)` and leave `def print_register(self)` out of your class definitions:

```
import functools

def dec_register(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_register(*args, **kwargs):
        (args[0].__class__.list_register_instances).append(args[0])
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper_register


dict_register_classes = {}
class register(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, attrs):
        dict_register_classes[name] = cls = type.__new__(meta, name, bases, attrs)  # assigniation from right to left
        cls.list_register_instances = []
        cls.print_register = classmethod(meta.print_register) # just create the classmethod manually!
        return cls

    def print_register(self):
        for element in self.list_register_instances:
            print(element)

    def print_register_class(cls):
        for element in cls.list_register_instances:
            print(element)

#
class Foo(metaclass=register):
    @dec_register
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Note, `print_register` doesn't have to be defined inside your metaclass, indeed, in this case, I would just define it at the module level:

```
def print_register(self):
    for element in self.list_register_instances:
        print(element)
...

class register(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, attrs):
        dict_register_classes[name] = cls = type.__new__(meta, name, bases, attrs)  # assigniation from right to left
        cls.list_register_instances = []
        cls.print_register = classmethod(print_register) 
        return cls

...
```

I think you understand metaclasses sufficiently, actually, it is your understanding of `classmethod` that is incorrect, as far as I can tell. If you want to understand how `classmethod` works, indeed, how method-instance binding works for regular functions, you need to understand *descriptors*. [Here's an enlightening link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). Function objects are descriptors, they bind the instance as the first argument to themselves when called on an instance (rather, they create a method object and return that, but it is basically partial application). `classmethod` objects are another kind of descriptor, one that binds the *class* to the first argument to the function it decorates *when called on either the class or the instance*. The link describes how you could write `classmethod` using pure python.